Which is the correct permutation action on a tensor product?
Greub, Multilinear Algebra, section 4.1 defines an action of $S_k$ on $\bigotimes^k V$ by defining it on pure tensors as:
$\sigma.(v_1\otimes ... v_k):= v_{\sigma^{-1}.1}\otimes ... v_{\sigma^{-1}.k}$
where $\sigma \in S_k$ and then extending linearly. He claims that this yields $\tau(\sigma.v) = (\tau\circ\sigma).v$. However, I get that $\tau(\sigma.v) = (\sigma\circ\tau).v$ since:
$\tau.[\sigma.v_1 \otimes ... v_k]$
$=\tau[v_{\sigma^{-1}.1} \otimes ... v_{\sigma^{-1}.k}]$
$=[v_{\tau^{-1}(\sigma^{-1}.1)} \otimes ... v_{\tau^{-1}(\sigma^{-1}.k)}]$
$=[v_{(\tau^{-1}\circ\sigma^{-1}).1} \otimes ... v_{(\tau^{-1}\circ\sigma^{-1}).k)}]$
$=v_{(\sigma\circ\tau)^{-1}.1} \otimes ... v_{(\sigma\circ\tau)^{-1}.k)}$
= $(\sigma\circ\tau).(v_1 \otimes ... v_k)$
To get the correct behaviour, it appears we should define:
$\sigma.(v_1\otimes ... v_k) := v_{\sigma.1}\otimes ... v_{\sigma.k}$
Then $\tau(\sigma.v) = (\tau\circ\sigma).v$.
Q. Which is correct?

Your error is a common type of "alias versus alibi" confusion. See also my answer here.

Your second equal sign seems to be the problematic one; the $\tau$ should go inside.
For fixed elements $v_1,\dots, v_n$, we can think of the tuple $v=(v_1,\dots, v_n)$ as a mapping $v:\{1,\dots, n\}\to V$. The definition of the action is then
\begin{align}
\sigma\cdot v:= v\circ\sigma^{-1},
\end{align}
where now we have an honest composition of $\sigma^{-1}:\{1,\dots, n\}\to \{1,\dots, n\}$ with $v:\{1,\dots, n\}\to V$. With this understanding, we have that for any $\sigma,\tau\in S_n$,
\begin{align}
\tau\cdot (\sigma\cdot v):=\tau\cdot (v\circ\sigma^{-1}):=(v\circ \sigma^{-1})\circ\tau^{-1}=v\circ(\tau\circ\sigma)^{-1}=:(\tau\circ\sigma)\cdot v,
\end{align}
as claimed.

Thanks, this really clarifies the issue.

The issue here is similar to proposed actions of $S_k$ on $\mathbf R[x_1,\ldots,x_k]$ and on $\mathbf R^k$ by
$$
\sigma(f(x_1,\ldots,x_k)) = f(x_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,x_{\sigma(k)})
$$
on polynomials $f(x_1,\ldots,x_k)$ and
$$
\sigma(c_1,\ldots,c_k) = (c_{\sigma(1)},\ldots,c_{\sigma(k)})
$$
on vectors $(c_1,\ldots,c_k)$.
It is easy to convince yourself that these are both left group actions, but in fact the second one is not: for all $v \in \mathbf R^k$, $\tau(\sigma(v))$ is $(\sigma\tau)(v)$, not $(\tau\sigma)(v)$!
See Examples 2.8 and 2.9 here.  You are making the same kind of mistake that is pointed out with $\mathbf R^k$ in Example 2.9.
To create a left group action of $S_k$ on $\mathbf R^k$ by acting on coordinates, we should replace $c_{\sigma(i)}$ in the formula with $c_{\sigma^{-1}(i)}$. Once you understand this, it will be clearer why the action of $S_k$ on $V^{\otimes k}$ in Greub's book is defined the way it is. Then see Corollary 5.18 here.
